# android java mediaplayer Service - how can I know if mediaPlayer is prepared?

Tags: java, android, service, prepare

I made a binded service with `MediaPlayer` controls which loads and play back audio. But as it happens, sometimes `mediaPlayer.prepare();` is not fast enough and it's not always prepared to playback.

So how can I make such method , something like `myService.prepare()` where I can ask for MediaPlayer to prepare and wait for it?

Comment: `prepare()` should be synchronous and block till it is complete, `prepareAsync()` is what would be causing your problem.

Comment: well, I just use prepare() but often got an illegal exception with that. I don't use prepareAsync ... If it blocks - why do I get this Illegal exception from time to time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may wait for the OnPrepared event to be triggered by the MediaPlayer.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener.html

Edit : prepare() is blocking only for files, so if you're working with something else, that might be the cause.

Comment: yeah, I know that, but how can I know from activity is mediaPlayer is prepared already or not ? my MediaPlayer is in Service and I have to make it prepared in one method (in Activity)

Comment: I'm working with files on SD card - mediaPlayer.setDataSource() method. Does it count for files, I guess? Strangely, same file can get Illegal exception with prepare()

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem : I guess you can use a boolean initialized to false, and set it to true in the callback. When you have to ask for the state of the MediaPlayer, just send the boolean value to your activity ?

Comment: Maybe.. but I've got something like audioService.prepare(); audioService.start(); if I'll put something in the midle to wait for boolean to be true - I'll kind of block my Activity and I've learned that it's a bad thing

Comment: If the service is holding the MediaPlayer, then only your service will be able to tell whether or not the MediaPlayer is ready to play. You can send a message to your Activity when its the case. There are many ways to do it, an easy one is to use Broadcast Messages

Comment: maybe.. but it complicates so much.. There are so many places in the code where I call prepare.. ok.. thank you for answer